# C# Itinerary application - repeated inquiry before proceeding

Tags: c#, console-application

I've been trying to refactor a C# console application that asks where a user would like to travel, records the location, repeats the question, and then either asks for another location or prints the locations the user has specified (ending the program).

Given the commented instructions in the code, I seem to have everything in place. However, in the ContinuePlanning() method it repeats a second time regardless of user response before continuing in the program and I'm having trouble figuring out why.

From what I can tell, the logic makes sense but I know I'm missing a simple step somewhere in the code. Can anyone lend some insight as to why this is occurring?

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Synopsis: Everyone loves a great vacation! This application helps you keep track of all the wonderful places on your bucket list.

namespace TravelPlanner
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Display header
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("========================================");
            Console.WriteLine(" TRAVEL PLANNER ");
            Console.WriteLine("========================================");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Helping you keep track of the places you will travel. \r\n");

            /*
            3. PLAN ITINERARY
            -------------------------
            [ After completing steps #1 and #2, lets take the optimization even further...
              Reviewing what you've accomplished, you will notice that each step now contains a single line
              of code. We've compartmentalized each action into a method, excellent refactoring!

              The while loop below contains these two actions. Looping over those actions is how we plan the
              itinerary. So lets migrate the loop and the nested actions into the middle of the Plan() method.
              The only thing left now is the creation of the list. Add one line that sets the value of
              "locations" to the calling of that method. Planning the itinerary has now be accomplished with
              one line within Main()!

              The Main() method has become an outline of the application... after displaying the header, we Plan(),
              then display what we've planned, and finally display a footer.

              Uh, oh... don't forget the syntax problem!
            ] */

                // Create List
                List<string> locations = new List<string>();

                // Repeat until all locations are added
                bool planning = true;
                while (planning)
                {

                    /*
                    1. GET LOCATION
                    -------------------------
                    [ Migrate the following, except for the last line, into the Itinerary class' (Itinerary.cs)
                      GetLocation() method. Then change the last line so "location," within locations.Add()
                      calls that GetLocation() method. Refer to the lesson on static classes/methods to see
                      how you can call methods from other classes.

                      Also, make sure to fix the validation's logic errors!
                    ] */

                    locations.Add(Itinerary.GetLocation());

                    /*
                    2. CONTINUE PLANNING
                    -------------------------
                    [ Migrate all of the following into the ContinuePlanning() method. Replace this with a
                      single line that sets the value of the "planning" variable to the returned value.

                      This validation also contains a logic error!
                    ] */

                    planning = Itinerary.ContinuePlanning(planning);

                }

            /*
            4. DISPLAY ITINERARY
               -------------------------
                [ The Itinerary class has allowed us to organize the code, containing all the methods (processes)
                  related to the planning of the itinerary: Plan(), GetLocation(), and ContinuePlanning().
                  Since the following code is used to display the itinerary, it should be there too.
                  
                  Migrate the following into the Display() method. Then replace with a call to that method.
                  Of course you'll need an argument for the "locations" list to display.

                  Carefully read the output to spot a syntax error... we want to practice string interpolation!
                ] */


            Itinerary.Display(locations);

            // -------------------------


            // Display footer
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("========================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Safe travels on your future trips!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }   

    // End class
    }
}
```

Itinerary.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

// Synopsis: Collection of methods used in the planning and displaying of travel itinerary locations.

namespace TravelPlanner
{
    public class Itinerary
    {

        // Plan itinerary
        public static List<string> Plan()
        {

            // Create list for locations
            List<string> locations = new List<string>();

            return locations;
        }


        // Request location from user
        public static string GetLocation()
        {
            // Initial request
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Console.Write("Where would you like to travel? ");
            string location = Console.ReadLine();

            // Validate user input 
            while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(location))
            {
                // Reminder not to leave blank
                Console.WriteLine("Please do not leave this blank! \r\n");

                // Ask again where they would like to go
                Console.Write("Where would you like to travel? ");

                // String for user input
                string newlocation = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            return location;
        }


        // Question - another location?
        public static bool ContinuePlanning(bool planning)
        {
            // Another location?
            Console.Write("Another location? (yes/no) ");
            string response = Console.ReadLine();

            // Validate user input
            if (response.ToLower() != "yes" || response.ToLower() != "no")
            {
                // Error message
                Console.WriteLine("Please only enter yes or no.");

                // Re-ask question
                Console.Write("Another location? (yes/no) ");
                response = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            // Continue planning?
            if (response.ToLower() == "no")
            {
                planning = false;
            }

            return planning;
        }

 
        // Display itinerary locations
        public static void Display(List<string> locations)
        {
            //Output the number of locations the user will visit
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($" You will take {locations.Count} trip(s).");

            //Output each location the user will visit
            for (int i = 0; i < locations.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" You will visit {locations[i]}.");
            }
        }


    // End class
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `GetLocation`, if the user enters a blank line, you create a new variable to hold the correct response: `string newlocation = Console.ReadLine();`. Instead, you should just assign `location` here, because that's what the method is returning. As it stands, `newlocation` is set and then discarded.

Answer (score 0):

> *"From what I can tell, the logic makes sense"*

That's probably because you're reading it as someone might say it in english, but not as a logical code statement.

- In English we would say, *"If they didn't answer with "yes" **or** "no", then ask them again."*
- In code we phrase it differently: *"If the answer wasn't "yes" **and** the answer wasn't "no", then ask them again"*

Here's why:

- The [conditional logical OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-) (`||`) will return `true` if either operand is `true` (and evaluation will stop at the first `true` result):

  - `false || false == false`
  - `false || true  == true`
  - `true  || false == true`
  - `true  || true  == true`
- This differs from the [conditional logical AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) (`&&`) which will return `true` only if *both* operands are true.

  - `false && false == false`
  - `false && true  == false`
  - `true  && false == false`
  - `true  && true  == true`

Now let's take a look at your `if` condition in `ContinuePlanning`:

```
if (response.ToLower() != "yes" || response.ToLower() != "no")
```

Now, if someone enters `"yes"`, the first part is `false` but the second part is `true`, so the condition will evaluate to `true`. Similarly, if they enter `"no"` (or any other input), the first part is `true`, so the condition will evaluate to `true`

Instead, we want to test that both the first part AND the second part are true, so we should use the `&&` operator:

```
if (response.ToLower() != "yes" && response.ToLower() != "no")
```

Now if they enter `"yes"` or `"no"`, only of those operands will be `true`, so the condition will evaluate to `false`. If they enter any other input, then *both* the conditions are `true`, which is what we're looking for.

---

Another problem is that this method takes in a `bool` argument, modifies it to `false` if the user enters `"no"`, and then returns it. The problem with this is that if the variable starts out to be `false`, then we return `false` no matter what the user enters. Also, this method doesn't *need* any arguments from the caller. We should just declare the variable locally instead.

We also only check once if they enter `"yes"` or `"no"`, but we should do it in a loop just in case they're really clumsy typists. :)

```
// Question - another location?
public static bool ContinuePlanning()
{
    // Start out assuming we will contiune planning
    bool continuePlanning = true;

    // Another location?
    Console.Write("Another location? (yes/no) ");

    // Get the user reponse and make it lower case
    string response = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

    // Validate user input
    while (response != "yes" && response != "no")
    {
        // Error message
        Console.WriteLine("Please only enter yes or no.");

        // Re-ask question
        Console.Write("Another location? (yes/no) ");
        response = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // If the user doesn't want to continue, set our variable
    if (response == "no") continuePlanning = false;

    return continuePlanning;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation. Instantly made me remember logic from a discrete math class I recently took (can't believe I forgot about that). This helped me understand it very well, I sincerely appreciate the help!